# Change View on Button Click with MVVM (No code Behind) and without Navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, xaml, mvvm

I'm using WPF MVVM.

I have a WCF Chat service which should perform certain validation operations (user credentials) in order to send a message to the chat window..

This of course happens the moment I press my Button "Login!".

What I want to accomplish is a new View (Chat window view) the moment I press login and the verification succeeded.

*Since I do not have yet a chat view, lets assume my chat view is my signup view (just for the principal of understanding how to switch a view on button click with an ICommand)

I'm going to post what I've done so:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type  ViewModels:LoginViewModel}">
        <Views:LoginView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:SignUpViewModel}">
        <Views:SignUpView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new AppViewModel();
    }
}
```

LoginViewModel.cs

```
    public class LoginViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public AuthenticatedUser AuthenticatedUser { get; set; }
    private string username;

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return username; }
        set {
            username = value;
            Notify();
        }
    }
    private string password;
    public string Password
    {
        get { return password; }
        set
        {
            password = value;
            Notify();
        }
    }

    public ConsoleLog ConsoleLog { get ; set; } // TODO: StringBuilder.
    public UserServiceProxy UserServiceProxy { get; set; }
    public ChatServiceProxy ChatServiceProxy { get; set; }

    public LoginViewModel()
    {
        AuthenticatedUser = AuthenticatedUser.Instance;
        UserServiceProxy = new UserServiceProxy();
        ChatServiceProxy = new ChatServiceProxy();
        SendLoginRequestCommand = new MyCommand(SendLoginRequest);
        ConsoleLog = new ConsoleLog();
        ConsoleLog.Document = "Binding Checker.";
    }

    public ICommand SendLoginRequestCommand { get; set; }

    private void SendLoginRequest()
    {
      LoginResponse response = UserServiceProxy.Login(new LoginRequest { UserName = UserName, Password = Password });
        ConsoleLog.Document += $"{response.IsSuccess} {response.Message}";
      if(response.IsSuccess == true)
        {
            AuthenticatedUser.Authentication = response.Authentication;
            JoinServiceResponse responseFromChatService = ChatServiceProxy.JoinService(new JoinServiceRequest());
            ConsoleLog.Document += responseFromChatService.Message;

            /* This is where I think the view should be changed,yet no success for a few days now.
             * 
             * 
             * 
             * 
             * 
             */
        }

    }

    private void LoginEventRaised(object sender, OnLoginEventArgs e)
    {
        ConsoleLog.Document += $"{e.UserName} has logged in.";
    }
}
```

SignUpViewModel.cs:

```
    public class SignUpViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }
    public ConsoleLog ConsoleLog { get; set; }
    public UserServiceProxy UserServiceProxy { get; set; }

    public ICommand OnClickSignUpCommand { get; set; }

    public SignUpViewModel()
    {
        UserServiceProxy = new UserServiceProxy();
        ConsoleLog = new ConsoleLog { Document = "Check Register."};
        OnClickSignUpCommand = new MyCommand(SendSignUpRequest);
    }

    private void SendSignUpRequest()
    {
      SignUpResponse response = UserServiceProxy.SignUp(new SignUpRequest { UserName = UserName, Password = Password, PasswordConfirm = PasswordConfirm });
        if(response.IsSuccess == true)
        {
            ConsoleLog.Document += $"{response.IsSuccess} {response.Message}";
            response.AllOtherUsers.ForEach(u => ConsoleLog.Document += $"{u.UserName} Signed up.");
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModelBase.cs:

```
    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public virtual void Notify([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

AppViewModel.cs:

```
    public class AppViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ViewModelBase currentView;

    public ViewModelBase CurrentView
    {
        get { return currentView; }
        set {
            currentView = value;
            Notify();
        }
    }

    public ICommand ViewLoginCommand { get; }
    public ICommand ViewSignUpCommand { get; }

    public AppViewModel()
    {
        ViewLoginCommand = new MyCommand(SetCurrentViewToLoginViewModel);
        ViewSignUpCommand = new MyCommand(SetCurrentViewToSignUpViewModel);
        CurrentView = new LoginViewModel(); //temporary loading the first view the use will see.
    }
    private void SetCurrentViewToLoginViewModel()
    {
        CurrentView = new LoginViewModel();
    }
    public void SetCurrentViewToSignUpViewModel()
    {
        CurrentView = new SignUpViewModel();
    }
}
```

LoginView.xaml (which is a user control):

```
    <Grid>
    <Button x:Name="login" Content="login" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="292,171,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="114" Height="33" Command="{Binding SendLoginRequestCommand}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="passwordTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="292,103,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Password}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="userNameTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="292,51,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding UserName}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="consoleLog" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,33,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path = ConsoleLog.Document}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="232" Width="218" />
    <Button x:Name="logout" Content="logout" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="292,232,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="114" Height="33"/>
</Grid>
```

SignUpView.xaml (this code isn't really neede for this question, but just in case):

```
    <Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="310,24,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding UserName}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="310,74,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Password}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="310,124,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding PasswordConfirm}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130"/>
    <Button x:Name="register" Content="Register" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="310,176,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" Command="{Binding OnClickSignUpCommand}"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding  Path=ConsoleLog.Document}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="289" Width="253"/>
</Grid>
```

I know I'm missing something here. Probably because I tried to solve the problem for a few days so I have lost track.

This is my login: (can't embedd yet)

[LoginView.xaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgcXm.png)

The moment I Press "Login", I need the next View to load:

[SignUpView.xaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctN0M.png)

I cannot offer any rep for this question. Still, I would really appreciate help.

Explored the net and could not find an appropriate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have realy provided to much code in your question, please see this [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
before posting your questions.

If I understood what you are trying to do in your program, your `AppViewModel` is your "MainNavigation" class which is responsible to manage all the view and navigate between them.

One solution that I can offer you is to add to your `LoginViewModel` an event which will be raised when the user has logged in successfully. in your `AppViewModel` you will be registered to this event and implement an handler which will change the `CurrentView` property to your `SignUpViewModel`.

the addition to the `LoginViewModel.cs` will look like this:

```
public class LoginViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    ...

    public delegate void UserLoginSuccessfullyHandler();
    public event UserLoginSuccessfullyHandler UserLoginSuccessfullyEvent;

    private void SendLoginRequest()
    {
      LoginResponse response = UserServiceProxy.Login(new LoginRequest { UserName = UserName, Password = Password });
        ConsoleLog.Document += $"{response.IsSuccess} {response.Message}";
      if(response.IsSuccess == true)
        {
            AuthenticatedUser.Authentication = response.Authentication;
            JoinServiceResponse responseFromChatService = ChatServiceProxy.JoinService(new JoinServiceRequest());
            ConsoleLog.Document += responseFromChatService.Message;

            // This is where you inform the AppViewModel to change his CurrentView
            if (UserLoginSuccessfullyEvent!= null)
                UserLoginSuccessfullyEvent();
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

the addition to the `AppViewModel.cs` will look like this:

```
    public class AppViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    ...

    public AppViewModel()
    {
        var loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
        loginViewModel.UserLoginSuccessfullyEvent += new UserLoginSuccessfullyHandler(myUserLoginSuccessfullyHandler);
        CurrentView = loginViewModel;
    }

    private void myUserLoginSuccessfullyHandler()
    {
        CurrentView = new SignUpViewModel();
    }

    ...
}
```

you can see more about events here [Events in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx)
.